# Eloquent INNER JOIN через JSON_CONTAINS

Tags: php, sql, eloquent

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой. Создаю такой SQL запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM books_sets INNER JOIN books ON JSON_CONTAINS(books_sets.books, books.id)
```

Соответственно, колонка `books` у `books_sets` содержит JSON в формате: `[1, 2]` (идентификаторы записей из таблицы `books`). Запрос выполняется корректно, возвращается то, что нужно мне.

Eloquent я использую отдельно от Laravel. Запросы формирую с помощью моделей.
Пример: `BooksSet::join(...)`.

Загвоздка в том, что я не могу сделать `join` с помощью Eloquent.
Пытался с помощью: `$query->join('books', 'JSON_CONTAINS(books_sets.books, books.id)')`. Ошибка в синтаксисе (очевидная, в принципе), происходит обёртка в колонку через символы `, добавляются операторы и` join` происходит через равенство.

Как должен выглядить запрос через Eloquent, чтобы получить тот же результат для запроса который в самом начале поста?

Comment: ```$query->join('books', DB::raw('JSON_CONTAINS(books_sets.books, books.id)'))```? ну или типа того...

Comment: @Akina спасибо, но я использую компонент Laravel отдельно и при использовании фасада DB вылезает такое: "A facade root has not been set.", можно ли как-то быстро исправить эту проблему, чтобы я смог проверить? Или есть какой-то другой способ. У меня модели и через них я делаю запросы. BookSet::join(...)

Comment: @Akina разобрался, использовал Manager для этой цели. Формируется вот такое в запросе: inner join `books` on JSON_CONTAINS(books_sets.books,books.id) = ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение для моей задачи, подходит идеально.

```
BooksSet::join('books', function ($join) {
    $join->on(function ($on) {
        $on->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(books_sets.books, books.id)');
    });
});
```